# Remote installation of packages on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, software-installation, package-management, system-installation

I am trying to work on a project where i am supposed to install softwares and packages on one system and it should replicate on other systems connected on LAN. 
How can i proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to introduce configuration management software like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com), [Chef](https://www.chef.io), [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com), etc.  See also [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software).

Comment: Puppet is a good choice.  It was designed somewhat more recently than cfengine.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be as follows:

1- Write a bash script *.sh file with the installation commands

2- Use the `scp` command to copy the *.sh script along with any binary files needed to the target machine

3- Connect using ssh to the target machine and run the *.sh script

**Note**: if you haven't used ssh before, you might have to install the openssh-server package first using `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` you can refer to this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) for more information about ssh.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question: remote install with `aptitude` in a terminal.  I use aptitude for all my local package-management because it's excellent.  Powerful search, nice UI for managing dependencies.  Lets you get a set of purges, upgrades, and installs lined up, and see what's going to happen before it happens.

To manage the set of packages installed on many machines, your best bet is a provisioning / config tool like puppet.  Each machine reads the config file, and figures out what it's supposed to have, then makes any changes necessary to bring that about.

The manual way to do deb packages is explained in an answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages.

```
m1$ dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list

m2$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
m2$ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
```